# Prepared Statement with SubQuery throwing error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have 2 tables `Employee` and `Department`.

`Department` has **One to Many** relationship with `Employee`.

`dep_id` is the foreign key column in the `Employee` table representing Department ID.

Query use case: get all employees from `Employee` table belonging to '**DEVELOPMENT**' department.

Following SQL statement works for me :

```
String sqlRead = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE AS e 
                  WHERE e.dep_id = (SELECT dep_id 
                                    FROM DEPARTMENT AS d 
                                    WHERE d.NAME = 'DEVELOPMENT')";
```

I want to create a PreparedStatement for the same. When I run the below Query I get SQL syntax error:

```
String sqlRead = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE AS e 
                  WHERE e.dep_id = (SELECT dep_id 
                                    FROM DEPARTMENT AS d 
                                    WHERE d.NAME = ?)";

PreparedStatement prepareStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlRead);    
prepareStatement.setString(1, "DEVELOPMENT");
ResultSet readResultSet = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
```

Error :

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1247)
>     at
>   com.tutorialspoint.eclipselink.service.PlainJDBC.main(PlainJDBC.java:44)

Could you help me in understanding, where my query is going wrong.

Comment: Why are you using a Subquery, when you can get the same results with much efficient methods such as INNER JOIN.

Comment: I am learning different ways of creating queries..

Comment: @NiteshAgrawal Please edit your question to include the full source code you have (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It looks like you are not using a prepared statement, but we can't be sure.

Comment: And, please let us know which line in your code throws the error: That is, which line is line 44.

Comment: The error is thrown from `executeQuery`, which you don't show in your example code. The most like cause is that you used `prepareStatement.executeQuery(sqlRead)` instead of the parameterless prepareStatement.executeQuery()`.

Comment: @O.Jones ResultSet readResultSet = prepareStatement.executeQuery(sqlRead); is line no 44

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Also... How can I mark this comment as accepted answer. Sorry I am new in posting and answering in stackoverflow, so asking ...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are absolutely correct. Thanks. Now that I see java doc, it says executeQuery() can not be called on PreparedStatement. Then I suppose this method should not have been on PreparedStatement class....

Comment: @NiteshAgrawal That is a historic error in its design as `PreparedStatement` extends `Statement`. This can't be corrected without breaking code that relies on that inheritance.